# Class cast exception when using AnyVal

Tags: scala

I have some generic code for managing entities and services in my project and i've run into strange problem yesterday. I've managed to minify snipped to this:

```
object Test extends App {

    trait Id extends Any {
        def id: Int
    }

    trait EntityWithId[I] {
        def id: Option[I]
    }

    case class UserId(id: Int) extends AnyVal with Id

    case class User(id: Option[UserId], password: String) extends EntityWithId[UserId]

    trait BaseService[I <: Id, E <: EntityWithId[I]] {
        def save(entity: E): I = entity.id.get // mock
    }

    trait UserService extends BaseService[UserId, User] {
        def encrypt(pass: String): String = pass // mock

        def encryptAndSave(user: User): UserId = 
            super.save(user.copy(password = encrypt(user.password)))
    }

    object UserService extends UserService

    val user1 = User(Some(UserId(1)), "jerzy")
    val user2 = User(Some(UserId(2)), "jerzy")

    UserService.save(user1) // passes
    UserService.encryptAndSave(user2) // fails
}
```

When I try to use `encryptAndSave` method from `UserService` strange exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: controllers.Test$UserId cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(Unknown Source)
    at controllers.Test$UserService$.controllers$Test$UserService$$super$save(Test.scala:32)
    at controllers.Test$UserService$class.encryptAndSave(Test.scala:29)
    at controllers.Test$UserService$.encryptAndSave(Test.scala:32)
    at controllers.Test$delayedInit$body.apply(Test.scala:38)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:309)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
    at controllers.Test$.main(Test.scala:8)
    at controllers.Test.main(Test.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

I've managed to fix it simply by changing `super.save()` to `this.save()`, but I don't have any clues why this is causing this problem.

Comment: that's definitely a value class bug, the byte code for the generated method for `super.save` is wrong and sure to fail. It could be a manifestation of [SI-6786](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6786), or something of the same kind...

Comment: Change trait UserService to class UserService to dodge the buggy super.